Den Terminplan oder dem Terminplan?
Für wann hat die Arzthelferin in den Terminplan geschrieben?
Warum in den Terminplan und nicht im Terminplan?

Es muss in den Terminplan heißen, weil es sich nicht um einen Ort, sondern um eine Richtung handelt.
Nun kannst du dich natürlich fragen, warum schreiben und ähnliche Verben mit einer Richtung verwendet werden.

Ich sprüh's auf jede Wand … (bekannte Liedzeile)

Das hängt damit zusammen, dass der Ort im Allgemeinen festlegt, wo man sich selbst befindet, während man schreibt:

Ich sprüh's im Herrenklo auf jede Wand …

Die Richtung gibt hingegen das Ding an, das beschriftet wird. Und das Akkusativobjekt die Nachricht:

Ich sprüh den Spruch im Herrenklo auf jede Wand …


…neue Männer braucht das Land.
